# Pseudo element tooltip fluid width

Tags: css, tooltip

here i got a css-only tooltip:

https://jsfiddle.net/r0zg014b/3/

I want that the :after pseudo element got a fluid width (also max-width) based on the text content.

At the fiddle you can see my tests.
atm i used `&#xa;` and `white-space: pre;` for lines breaks, but i don't want these :D

`display: table;` worked for safari, but e.x. not for firefox:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0zg014b/4/

Any solution on this?

Comment: I don't understand what width you actually want.  you want it "based on the text content" _how_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are suffering from is not related to your styles being applied to pseudo elements. You want an absolutely positioned element to grow potentially wider than its relatively positioned container, which by default it will not do. You can specify your tooltips to always have a width of e.g. `340px` and this will work. However, at the moment the tooltip will be at most as wide as the `span` it is being applied on.

One workaround (that feels hacky) is to extend the width of the `span` elements. You can do this by applying a large padding and negative margin on the elements, as follows.

```
padding: 0 170px;
margin: 0 -170px;
```

This will extend the width of the span, but make it appear the width it should have because of the negative margins. There are bad side effects of doing this, however. You can see that in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04xvn6rr/) (I simply applied the changes to yours). Most notably, note that the tooltip appears when the mouse is close to the text, because the span is made wider. Also, the tooltip can appear at the wrong position when a line break occurs.

A nicer approach is possible, namely by having an absolutely positioned container that always has width `340px` and in that have the actual tooltip, with `max-width: 340px`. This does require an extra container element however and thus is not possible with your pseudo element approach... If you would like to see that though, then I can create a demo.

Comment: You are very welcome. Will you go with the padding/margin approach, or introduce some containers?

Comment: I'll go for a lightweight js solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
body {
  padding: 140px;
}
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: solid 5px transparent;
  border-right: solid 5px transparent;
  border-top: solid 5px rgba(34, 50, 84, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5px);
}
[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  padding: 10px 16px;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(34, 50, 84, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5px);
}
```

```html
<span data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">Short</span>
<span data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.">Long</span>
<span data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.">Want</span>
```

Comment: this with a max-width for the tooltip, e.x. 300px :)